# Free API-accessible dashboard for a client to manage website content

Tags: gratis, web-apps, api

My (web development) client is a 3D artist who wants an online portfolio with manageable content. I have built an AngularJS app for him which can fetch JSON data from APIs and display them as desired. I've been testing the application with "dummy" data generating APIs such as [jsonplaceholder](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/).

Now I need a dashboard for my client to manage his content. Something like the WordPress admin dashboard but with the following **requirements**:

- It has to be light. Preferably headless.
- It has to be free (as in gratis).
- Of course, it has to produce a JSON feed.

A typical "content block" for him will be a title, a little bit of text and many images. Maybe even an embedded video.

I have been considering the JSON API plugins for WordPress but I'm trying to find a lighter solution, or anything more appropriate that I'm missing. To be honest, I don't know if such a thing exists. I hope you do!